# Codeigniter - Displaying Database records in a table/list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeingiter and searched everywhere for a fix on this but nothings working for me yet the issue is so simple..
i want to display my database records in a list or table and make them available to click/ use etc.. but i keep getting an undefined variable error for query (which i thought was defined) and an invalid argument supplied foreach error.. any help will be massively appreciated

Controller

```
public function viewtemplate()
{
    $this->load->model('Template_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->Template_model->viewtemplate();
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

Model

```
function viewtemplate()
{
    $query =  $this->db->get('users'); 
    return $query->result() ;
}
```

View

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->idtemplates; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->templatestyle ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->users_temp_id; ?></td>
  
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

**Error 1**

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: query
>
> Filename: views/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 154

**Error 2**

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 154

Comment: post your error message?

Comment: edited with errors @Muhammad

Comment: before passing the data to view check if you get something in return to function call.

Comment: var_dump() your data in controller like this and check what you are receiving var_dump($dats['query']);

Comment: You are not designating $query as a data result. Add $data['query'] = $query->result();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the view before the foreach the following to see if your controller is sending any data to the view:

```
<?php echo var_dump($query);?>
```

if the variable $query is not an array thats why you are getting an error inside the foreach, since is trying to use a property that doesnt exist.

**Edit:**

So the real problem was the code was on another controller function and he was seeing the index of the controller, where the query variable wasnt defined.

Comment: its showing up NULL, however there is records iny my database, and table names etc are correct

Comment: change in your model function to the following:

       function viewtemplate()
       {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $query =  $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result() ;
       }

Comment: Can you upload the project?? i'll check it for you, since everything seens to be ok

Comment: sure, upload where?

Comment: my database table is actually 'templates' instead of 'users' but this it is still broken even when i chnaged this

Comment: it is a very big project, will take very long uploading there, you have teamviewer and i can show you?

Comment: try this `$this->load->model('Template_model', '', TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to write the semicolon in

```
<td><?php echo $row->templatestyle ?></td> as
<td><?php echo $row->templatestyle; ?></td>
```

then try to change the variable `$query` in your controller.